# Passing Default and optional Arguments in Python

Tags: python, function, arguments, default, optional-arguments

```
def fun( key=False,*var):
  if key is False:
     print(var)
     return 0
  print("Key is true")
  return 0
fun(1,2,3)
```

**I have not passed a value of key in fun(1,2,3)**. Hence the default value of key i.e. **key=False**. But the output is:

```
Key is true
```

These Cases are contradicting. **Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 3):

But you did pass `1` for `key`. And `[2,3]` for `*var`.

Positional arguments you supply to a function are bound to argument variables *in order* they appear. The exception are keyword arguments, but you have to explicitly name them when calling the function (and you are not doing that).

So, you'll have to reverse the order and put keyword argument `key` at the end. But that would be an invalid syntax in Python 2. The standard solution (that works *in both Python 2 and Python 3*) is to switch to keyword arguments dictionary and to supply default values for arguments only when [popping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) them:

```
>>> def fun(*var, **kwargs):
...    key = kwargs.pop('key', False)
...    print(key)
... 
>>> fun(1,2,3)
False
>>> fun(1,2,3, key=True)
True
```

Since Python 3.0 (see [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) for the  new syntax), you *can have* keyword arguments after a list of positional arguments, like this:

```
>>> def fun(*var, key=False):
...    print(key)
... 
>>> fun(1,2,3)
False
>>> fun(1,2,3, key=True)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that Python will take the first argument in `fun(1,2,3)` to be `key`, as that is the first and only positional argument. The fact that it is optional is besides the point. As `1` is clearly not `False`, it does not print `var` but instead prints `Key is true.`. If you want to have `key` accessible only through things like `fun(key=True)`, you require this code instead.

```
def fun(*var,**kwargs):
    if "key" in kwargs and kwargs["key"] is False:
        print(var)
        return 0
    print("Key is true")
    return 0
fun(1,2,3)
fun(1,2,key=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just working as expected. Just to debug, added a print statement.

```
def fun( key=False,*var):
    print key, var
    if key is False:
         print(var)
         return 0
    print("Key is true")
    return 0

fun(1,2,3)
```

a quick check in command-line ... which explains.

```
>>> print True == 1
True
>>> 
>>> 1 is False
False
>>>
```

that is the reason, control is not entering inside if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(*var, key=False):
  if key is False:
    print(var)
    return 0
  print("Key is true")
return 0
fun(1,2,3)
fun(1,2,3, key=True)
```

In any function declaration, if you have both position and keyword arguments, then positional arguments needs to be at first place then keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Default arguments shall be put in the end.
Otherwise, it will take the parameter passed for processing in the default argument as well.

```
def fun(*var, key=False):
  if key is False:
     print(var)
     return 0
  print("Key is true")
  return 0
fun(1,2,3)
```

Output: `(1, 2, 3)`

```
def fun(*var, key=False):
    if key is False:
        print(var)
        return 0
    print("Key is true")
    return 0

fun(1, 2, 3, key=True)
```

Output: `Key is true`